# Change color of plot created with compare(), from system id toolbox

Tags: matlab

The title says what I'd like.

The `compare(zv, mtf)` function generates a figure with two lines, a gray one, representing the real system data carried by zv variable, and another blue line representing the model's response to the same signal. How can I change the color of the blue line?

Compare's documentation gives the example of using 'r' for red, but I want to pass a specific RGB color. The syntax `compare(zv, mtf,'color', [219/256 134/256 7/256])` gives the following error:

> The string "color" is not a valid plot style.

I'm running R2015b (32bit). Unfortunately I wont be able to upgrade to a more recent version for some weeks still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, but it is not very intuitive, and the legend color does not update with the update line color...

A better way is probably to obtain the response of the system and goodness of fit by calling

```
[y_sys,fit,~] = compare(z1, sys);
```

and plot these results yourself (see the [docs](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/compare.html#mw_e1982839-836d-4b09-818b-d8568e1ce59e)).

```
% load sample data and system
load iddata1 z1;
sys = tfest(z1,3);

% give the tf system a name
tf_name = 'system';
sys.Name = tf_name;

% compare in figure
fig = figure(1); clf;
compare(z1,sys)

% get handle for line of system
children = get(gca, 'Children');
grp = findobj(children, '-regexp', 'DisplayName', tf_name); % use system.Name here!
l = grp.Children; % handle to line object

% get old color
color_old = l.Color; % same as output of 'lines(1)' when using default colors

% find all lines with color
ls = findobj(fig, 'Color', color_old);
% set new color
set(ls, 'Color', [219/256 134/256 7/256])
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. In the end, the plot given by `compare()` is meant for quick evaluation.